# VSCode shows Unresolved import for my custom class

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

`util.py` is located in `/path/to/the/class` and `util.py` has `class StockUtil`.

Have added

```
"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
    "/path/to/the/class"
]
```

in `settings.json`.

However, `from util import StockUtil` still raises `Unresolved import: StockUtil`.

Does anyone have the same experience? Thanks.

[image: Unresolved import]

Comment: Did you tried running it outside your IDE/Dev Environment?

Comment: @AryanMishra Yes, all code runs safe and sound. Just want to eliminate `Unresolved import` warning. Thanks.

Comment: Umm, Probably no idea on how to do that, not a vs code man, good luck

Answer (score 0):

After re-installing VSCode, everything looks fine, thanks.